# ¿Cómo mantengo el disabled fijo al llamarlo a través de una función?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy tratando de deshabilitar algunos input cuando pulso un botón, pero no me está funcionando y no sé cómo solucionarlo.

```
    $("#butM").click(function () {
        url = "IOvariables.html";
        name = '"M".ED.ON';
        val = auxM;
        sdata = escape(name) + '=' + val;
        $.post(url, sdata, function (result) { });

        st();
    });

    function st() {
        $("#input_type1").prop("disabled", true);
    }
```

Este sería el código del botón:

```
<!--Marcha-->
<input id='valM' type="hidden" value="1" />
<button id="butM" class="img_button"><img class="img_button" src="img/marcha.png" /></button>
```

y este uno de los input que quiero deshabilitar:

```
<form action="" id="form_mVel">
    <input id="input_mVel" class="input_type1" type="number" step="1" placeholder="RPM" value="" min="0" max="1500">
</form>
```

El problema es que cuando llamo a la función no parece mantener el estado de *disabled*...

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código del tramo html donde está el input? Por otro lado... ¿habías cambiado alguna opción con `$.ajaxSetup`?

Comment: Ok... ahora que se ve el resto de código, te comento que es porque utilizas `$("#input_type1")`. Si lo haces accediendo al ìd` ha de ser `$("#input_mVel")`. Si quieres utilizar la clase, debería ser `$(".input_type1")`. Tú verás lo que prefieres... Ahora mismo quizá sólo tengas un elemento con esa clase. Pero para eso está la elección: deshabilitar sólo un elemento, o todos los que contengan una clase.

Comment: Si, me he dado cuenta de ese fallo, lo he tenido al probar tantas opciones. Pero sigue sin funcionar. A través de la consola estoy viendo que entro en la función, pero no me deshabilita el input. Sin embargo sin ninguna función de por medio si que lo deshabilita, pero claro, pierdo totalmente el control de cuando quiero deshabilitar el input.

Comment: Por casualidad... pon la llamada a `st();` justo después del `$("#butM").click(function () {` y coméntanos si funciona. Siempre después de corregir lo de `$("#input_mVel").prop("disabled", true);`, claro.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar. La función es llamada y actúa, pero no funciona para el disabled.

Comment: Luisan, pues algún otro error tendrás, porque como puedes ver en https://jsfiddle.net/laabuelita/eLc5tsg3/1/ funciona correctamente. Por supuesto, he modificado un par de líneas del js porque no tengo la llamada al `$.post` ni el valor de `auxM`, que no se sabe cuál es y la imagen del botón

Comment: A mi m e funciona correctamente, solo con cambiar el selector, a esto:
`$(".input_type1").prop("disabled", true);` Incluso teniendo un error con el POST, la ejecución continúa. A simple vista es el único problema que veo al código que has aportado.

Comment: Por lo que observo, no se ejecuta dicha función en principio por que el **id** al que estas haciendo referencia no existe, el id del input es  $("#input_mVel") y no $("#input_type1"), por otra parte estas haciendo mal la petición Ajax, estas combinando la  versión minimizada con la extendida y como falla no cae en el 
_succes_ y no ejecuta dicha función, la **funcion st** funciona correctamente si le quitas la petición, pero como falla la petición, Ajax no ejecutara la **funcion st**.